# "Not all code paths returns a value" error when upgrading thrown errors to SvelteKit 2

Tags: migration, sveltekit

I'm upgrading a project to SvelteKit 2 following [this guide](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating-to-sveltekit-2#redirect-and-error-are-no-longer-thrown-by-you)

Previous, to throw an error from a load function you had to explicitly throw it, like this:

```js
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load = async ({ fetch, params }) => {
    if (!params.slug)
        throw error(400, {
            error: 'No slug defined.',
            message: 'Format: wb_customer_slug/pricing_page_slug',
        });
```

Now you no longer need to throw it

> Previously, you had to throw the values returned from error(...) and redirect(...) yourself. In SvelteKit 2 this is no longer the case — calling the functions is sufficient.

But I get a typescript error `Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)`

I can get rid of that message with a `return error(400, {...`, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to solve it

Is there some way to tell typescript that the `error` function will in fact throw? Or is there any better way to handle it?